# Minecraft Color code parser

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, minecraft, string-parsing

I am trying to make a minecraft color code parser. I take the original text from a textbox and display the resulting text in the rich textbox.
The original text would look something like this:

> &4Red

Here, `&4` means the text after that should be red color.

> abc&4Red&fWhite

This text should look like abc in default color (black), "Red" in red, "White" in white.

So how can I parse the text to separate the text to "abc", "&4Red" and "&fWhite" ?

Comment: What problems are you having? Have you tried anything at all yet?

Comment: Of course, I tried but I have no idea how to separate pieces of text to like "abc","&4Red" and "&fWhite" in the above text.

Comment: If you need help parsing strings, ask about parsing strings. Your question right now sounds as if you're asking us to make this for you.

Comment: Ok now. I have thought a lot on ways to make it separated but got no idea.

Comment: Well, delete this question, go try one of the ways you thought of, if it works great! If it did not then come back here and ask a new question showing what you tried and explain what went wrong. Did you even try googling "Split string C#" yet?

Comment: You could try [String.Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [String.IndexOf()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)

Comment: I am going to give you a little general advice about programming, break your problem down in to its smallest parts and solve them individually. You have three problems 1)How do I split `abc&4Red&fWhite` in to `abc`, `&4Red`, and `&fWhite`. 2)How do I strip off `&#` off of a text then store the color the number represented with the text 3)How do I display colored text in a rich text box. **Focus on one problem at a time**, write up a simple program and just try to get the string splitting part, then try doing just the parsing part, then try doing just the display part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to learn about

1. basic C#
2. Regex
3. LINQ
4. Anonymous types
5. Delegates

but this does the trick :

```
        var txt = "abc&4Red&fWhite";

        // Add color code Black for first item if no color code is specified
        if (!txt.StartsWith("&"))
            txt = "&0" + txt;

        // Create a substrings list by splitting the text with a regex separator and
        // keep the separators in the list (e.g. ["&0", "abc", "&4", "Red", "&f", "White"])
        string pattern = "(&.)";
        var substrings = Regex.Split(txt, pattern).Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i)).ToList();

        // Create 2 lists, one for texts and one for color codes
        var colorCodes = substrings.Where(i => i.StartsWith("&")).ToList();
        var textParts = substrings.Where(i => !i.StartsWith("&")).ToList();

        // Combine the 2 intermediary list into one final result
        var result = textParts.Select((item, index) => new { Text = item, ColorCode = colorCodes[index] }).ToList();
```

Comment: LINQ was the thing I couldn't learn properly.

Comment: Well yeah, I have learnt it now. :)